# Android locationlistener not showing users correct location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

When I use following code and get my current location I will get location very much near to my location but not mine? why is that? 
thank you in advance ![this is what happens red marker is what i get as my location and blue dot is my actual location by google maps ][1]

```
package com.example.routepilot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.routepilot.GoTo.GPSTracker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    String stringLatitude;
    String stringLongitude;
    String country;

    String city;

    String postalCode;
    String addressLine;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
            stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);

            stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);

            country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);

            city = gpsTracker.getLocality(this);

            postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(this);

            addressLine = gpsTracker.getAddressLine(this);

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("################################### cannot get location");
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(stringLatitude);

        Double lon = Double.parseDouble(stringLongitude);

        System.out.println("##################### doubel lat -" + lat);
        /*
         * String lati= bundle.getString("latitude"); String longi=
         * bundle.getString("longitude"); String country=
         * bundle.getString("country"); String city= bundle.getString("city");
         * String postalcode= bundle.getString("postalcode"); String address=
         * bundle.getString("address");
         */

        LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(mylocation).title(country + " " + city)
                .snippet(postalCode + " " + addressLine)
                // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow))
                .draggable(false));

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Directing you to the web site";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

                Intent i3 = new Intent(Map.this, Webpage.class);
                startActivity(i3);

            }
        });

        /*
         * // Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a
         * rectangle PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
         * .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)) .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0)) //
         * North of the previous point, but at the same longitude .add(new
         * LatLng(37.45, -122.2)) // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
         * .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2)) // Same longitude, and 16km to the
         * south .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.
         * 
         * // Get back the mutable Polyline Polyline polyline =
         * mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
         */

        PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(6.927078600000000000, 79.861243000000060000),
                        new LatLng(6.934078600000000000, 79.561243000000060000))
                .width(5).color(Color.RED);

        mMap.addPolyline(line);

        LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(6.934078600000000000, 79.561243000000060000);

        GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions().image(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow))
                .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
        mMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lon),
                14.0f));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    }

    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
        private final Context mContext;

        // flag for GPS Status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        android.location.Location location;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        // The minimum distance to change updates in metters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10
                                                                        // metters

        // The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1
                                                                        // minute

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracker(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }

        public android.location.Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;

                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("Network", "Network");

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }

                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                updateGPSCoordinates();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error : Location",
                        "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
            }

            return location;
        }

        public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in
         * your app
         */

        public void stopUsingGPS() {
            if (locationManager != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         */
        public double getLatitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         */
        public double getLongitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         */
        public void showSettingsAlert() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("title");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("message");

            // On Pressing Setting button

            // On pressing cancel button

            alertDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
         * 
         * @return null or List<Address>
         */
        public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
            if (location != null) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                            latitude, longitude, 1);
                    return addresses;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Error : Geocoder",
                            "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Try to get AddressLine
         * 
         * @return null or addressLine
         */
        public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

                return addressLine;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get Locality
         * 
         * @return null or locality
         */
        public String getLocality(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String locality = address.getLocality();

                return locality;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get Postal Code
         * 
         * @return null or postalCode
         */
        public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

                return postalCode;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get CountryName
         * 
         * @return null or postalCode
         */
        public String getCountryName(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                return countryName;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.gc();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your current location then you could use this code..

put this code where you want to retrieve your location

```
if (gpstracker.canGetLocation()) {
            double lattitude = gpstracker.getLatitude();

            double longitude = gpstracker.getLongitude();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please turn on Your GPS.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

// create a class with the name GPSTracker and add the following code

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
    boolean canGetLocation=false;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=10;  //10 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1; //1 minute
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext=context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        locationManager=(LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.canGetLocation=true;
            if(isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                if(locationManager!=null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if(location!=null)
                            {
                                latitude=location.getLatitude();
                                longitude=location.getLongitude();
                            }
                }
            }
            if(isGPSEnabled)
            {
                if(location==null)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                }
                if(locationManager != null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null)
                    {
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS()
    {
        if(locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled .Do you want to go to settings menu ?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

//if there is any other query then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because you are getting `Location` from two different sources.

To fix that, remove all the code related to getting location from `LocationManager` (80% of your code) and replace it with simple call to:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location currentLocation) {
        // ...
    }
}
```